# containsString: issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

expression contains XXXXXX.DATETIME
array contains {DATE, DATETIME}

On the loop, checking the expression contains DATE.
Both the things are true. But I want only DATE has to go through.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"DATE", @"DATETIME", nil]];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSString *formatType = [array objectAtIndex:i]; 
    if ([expression containsString:formatType]){
        NSLog(@"%@", expression);
    }
}
```

Is there any other options other than containsString ?

Comment: `isEqualToString:` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, this is my guess:

1. You have a collection (`array`) containing a number of words some of which are *prefixes* of others (e.g. `DATE` is a prefix of `DATETIME`). This is a *dynamic* array, i.e. you don't know in advance what the words will be (or else you would trim it at compile time).
2. You have a string (`expression`) which may contain one or more of the words in your collection.
3. For every word in your collection if your string contains one or more occurrences of that word then you wish to do something (in your example represented by `NSLog`) **unless** your collection also contains another word which is a prefix of the word, which means your string also contains the *shorter* word, in which case you *only* wish to report a match for the *shorter* word.

If this reading of your question is correct then preprocessing your collection so it does not contain any words which are extensions of others is one way to tackle this. In pseudo code this would be:

```
array = original collection, say "ERA", "DATETIME", "DATE"
sortedArray = lexicographic sort of array, e.g. see NSArray's sortedArrayUsingComparator:
   our sample would produce "DATE", "DATETIME", "ERA"

lastWord = first word of sortedArray
trimmedArray = new mutable array containing just lastWord

for each nextWord in sortedArray
   if NOT lastWord is prefix of nextWord (see NSString's hasPrefix:)
      add nextWord to trimmedArray
      lastWord = nextWord
   end if
end for
```

The end result of the above with our sample would be `@[ "DATE", "ERA" ]`. Use this result in your original code instead of `array`.

HTH